# Unable to upload large graphql schema to aws appsync

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am trying to upload my graphql schema to aws appsync. My graphql schema is nearly 5000 lines long. I tried uploading using cli and gui, both.

(1.) When using cli, I am continually getting error "Failed to parse schema document - ensure it's a valid SDL-formatted document."

(2.) When using gui, the pipes in all the unions in my graphql schema ( eg. union UnionType = Type1 | Type2 | Type3 ) are replaced with whitespaces, causing syntax error. After solving this by manual replacement of whitespaces, the tab becomes unresponsive, and needs to be killed.

I tried uploading a small graphql schema with a union from cli, and it worked successfully. However, from gui, it caused the same error of replacing pipes with whitespaces in union.

I need help understanding this behaviour with aws cli and aws console.

Comment: How big is your schema?

Comment: In terms of file size, 134KB. In terms of number of lines, upwards of 5600 lines.

Comment: As to point 1, that's the 'catch all' message for a schema that the service couldn't parse. Could you share a request id, relative timestamp, and region in which you called? I can investigate further.

Comment: Same issue here. Any solution ?

Comment: We finally ended up using https://github.com/sid88in/serverless-appsync-plugin , as it provided us with the flexibility of adding our graphql resolvers and everything inside the serverless.yaml file. This simplified our build process, as we are anyways using serverless

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similar issue and AppSync didn't allow to put any comments in it with just only one # symbol.

Make sure you have no comments with just one # and use double sharps ##
Anyway, it happens you have some invalid format or syntax AppSync doesn't support yet.

Comment: This was similar for me – I commented my `enum` & it rejected it. Without comments in the enum, it was 100%.

Comment: I had sort of a combination of these two issues: comments starting with `#` inside of an `enum` were rejected, but comments starting with `##` were simply ignored (they are not visible in the console editor).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that, in our case, the problem was the existence of reserved keys defined in out schema ([DynamoDB reserved words](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html)) even though we are not using Dynamo at all.

Comment: Does Query count? I see the word QUERY in the reserved list, but the docs use type Query https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-appsync-readme.html.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when attempting to extend/implement one interface with another interface. Turns out only a type can implement an interface.